# Avoiding the timeout exception while connecting to a https url to send request to a web-service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl

In a dotNet mvc application, while trying to send requests to a http url, my application is working as expected. However, when I try to send requests to a https url, I get the following error ( upon publishing the app in IIS and running it in a web browser) :

```
Server Error in '/dotnetstage' Application.
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.63.64.146:443
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.63.64.146:
```

I understand that it has got something to do with the SSL certificates, so I found that there's a way to ignore certificate validation:

```
 WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(reqURL);
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; }; //this line works for the certificate validation ignoring
```

Even then, I am getting the same error. I have two queries:

- Am I adding the ServicePointManager line at the proper place? If not
  what is the correct location where you add this in your code?
- Is there anything else I need to take care of ?

Any help or at least a pointer towards the right approach will be higly appreciated. Stack Overflow helped me a lot with learning to code in c# mvc apps and build complex caller applications in a matter of 4 weeks and I look forward to getting a quick solution to this as well. Thanks. :)

Comment: Whats the point of using certificates if you just ignore their authenticity? That ServerCertificateValidationCallback hack should not be used in production.

Comment: @scheien Good question. Well currently , we are not concerned with the authenticity of the certificates else we would have created a certificate store in the code and processed the same. We just want to demonstrate other functionalities of the code which are not dependent on the SSL certificate(s).

Answer (score 1):

The ServerCertificateValidationCallback  should be defined first before making the web request. But in your case the issue is totally different it could be that the web server side code crashed before it could send a response back.